# select box with ngModel is not populating the selected value

Tags: angularjs

I am having a JSON reponse data which is an array representing country code and description

```
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Aruba"}],"codeValueCode":"ABW"},
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Afghanistan"}],"codeValueCode":"AFG"},     
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Angola"}],"codeValueCode":"AGO"},
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Anguilla"}],"codeValueCode":"AIA"},
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Åland Islands"}],"codeValueCode":"ALA"},  
 {"codeDescList":[{"desc":"Albania"}],"codeValueCode":"ALB"}
```

I stored the above array in angularJS scope object as follows

```
  $scope.codeValueData = response.data;
```

I created select box for countries

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <select ng-model="profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode" ng-options="codeValue.codeDescList[0].desc for codeValue in codeValueData track by codeValue.codeValueCode">
    </select>
 </div>
```

The select box is created correctly  like below

```
<option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
<option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AGO">Angola</option>
<option value="AIA">Anguilla</option>
<option value="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="ALB">Albania</option>
```

The problem with my code is  if profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode is referring to the value "AGO"  the select box is not showing the the country "Angola".  The select box is showing blank.

I am new to angularJS.   Please help to resolve this issue.  Thank you

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you saying that your select list populates, but once you click it, the option disappears?

Comment: Show me when and where to assign the value of profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode ? first look to code everything is right may be issue in profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode.

Comment: my select box is populating countries but  not selected/showing the value in select box as the value of the ng-model.    Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do can be achieved more easily with an `ng-repeat`. Try this:

```
<select ng-model="profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode">
      <option ng-repeat="item in codeValueData" value="{{item.codeValueCode}}">
           {{item.codeDescList[0].desc}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5s0b0jnz/

Answer (score 0):

Writing below select  statement worked for me

```
 <select ng-model="profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode" ng-options="codeValue.codeValueCode as codeValue.codeDescList[0].desc for codeValue in codeValueData">
```

The select box is populated as

```
<option value="0">Aruba</option>
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Angola</option>
<option value="3">Anguilla</option>
<option value="4">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="5">Albania</option>
```

and Selectiong Angola is storing as "AGO" in the model  "profileBizObj.preferredAddress.countryCode" which exactly I needed.

Thank You all for the help

Answer (score -1):

Your ng-options is `ng-options="codeValue.codeDescList[0].desc for codeValue in codeValueData track by codeValue.codeValueCode">`, it means, use the `codeValue` will be bound to model , and the `...desc` as the displayed value. So when your model value is `AGO`, it can not be referred to some object in codeValueData.

You should set your option value like `AGO` with this:

```
ng-options="codeValue.codeValueCode as codeValue.codeDescList[0].desc for codeValue in codeValueData track by codeValue.codeValueCode">
```

Then the `codeValueCode` will be applied to your model. And in reverse, for some model value like `AGO`, the related option will be selected.

Comment: Personaly, I tried that before answering below. I got `Error: Syntax Error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 15 of the expression [codeValueData track by codeValue.codeValueCode] starting at [track by codeValue.codeValueCode].`

Comment: Just remove track by, should not use 'track by' with 'as'

Comment: It is not what the documentation says: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions . I think your answer is correct in theory, but for whatever reason it does not work in practice.

Comment: In that document, it is said that the `track by` is used to track the identity of the items by the track by expression. It is not used to set the model value as `track by expression `. Just as what I said, in your previous code, the model is the code object, but not the code value(the track by expression). If you want to set the model, you should use `select .. as ..`

Comment: If you use `item.code as item.label for item in items track by item.id `, in my understanding, the track by `item.id` will evaluate the `id` of the model (defined by `as`), then it will try to find `item.code.id`. You can read the part of `select as and track by ` section in that document.